# Now I'm using EF 6 database first and i need to add new table

Tags: database, entity-framework, edmx

I'm using EF 6 database first. Now i need to add new table to my project. Can i add this table into .edmx Main model and from it update my DB but have Mapping error? Or i need create new empty EF .edmx model and from it update DB  instead of an Main model. And then update Main model using Update Model From Database option. Thnx.

Comment: do you have any code to share? and it seems there are a few questions here - which is of primary concern?

Comment: My understanding is that you need to update your database 'first' then regenerate your edmx. There are a few questions like this on SO already.

Comment: I know. But it's easy create new entity in exist .edmx with all relation, foreign keys to see scheme.